# Undefined variable: store_id Error trying to fix Magento CE 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Magento CE 1.9.1.0 and trying to fix a plugin that is suppose to sync my products with the jet.com shopping portal. Unfortunately the developer has not responded to any request for help I am trying to fix it myself. its installed correctly and it is all configured. However when I go to sync an item to jet.com I see the following in my system log file

Undefined variable: store_id in app/code/local/MKMage/Jet/Helper/Data.php on line 65

I am wondering if anyone knows how to edit the below to fix this error?
I tried adding the below to line 65 right after the else{ but got the same error

```
$store_id = = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

The Data.php file is too big to past so you can see it here
http://bit.ly/2bZnrcl

Comment: $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); should work. (without the extra "=". Assuming that this is a backend module, try adding "$store_id = 0" in line 26, just to try it

Comment: Hmm when I did that I get a
2016-08-22T14:13:36-04:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52

Answer (score 1):

`$store_id` never gets defined according to the block of code I just saw.

Just underneath the line that has `public function synchronizeProduct($id){` add this:

```
$store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

That should fix it. That will pass in the **current** store id. However if you always want to make sure you are editing default values, you can do this:

```
$store_id = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::DEFAULT_STORE_ID;
```

Comment: @user1739740 did my answer help you out?